Are there other authentication method than the basic auth available for the Azure Container Registry webhook (push event towards app service linux)?
I am using terraform to setup the Azure container registry webhook like this with basic auth disabled:
resource "azurerm_container_registry_webhook" "cr_webhook_myapp" {
  name                = "myappnamewebhook"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_container_registry.cr_mycontainerregistry.resource_group_name
  registry_name       = data.azurerm_container_registry.cr_mycontainerregistry.name
  location            = data.azurerm_container_registry.cr_mycontainerregistry.location

  # disabled registry webhooks using basic auth with app service kudu
  # service_uri = "https://$kudu_username:kudu_password@myappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/registry/webhook"
  service_uri = "https://${azurerm_linux_web_app.webapp_myapp.name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/registry/webhook"

  status      = "enabled"
  scope       = "myapp:latest"
  actions     = ["push"]
  custom_headers = {
  }
  tags = {
    source = "terraform"
  }
}

But the webhook push event fails by returning with a 401 code, trying to connect to the 'myapp' AppService endpoint.
Ideally, I'd like to use a system-managed identity to authenticate the container registry to the app service, or some EntraID application.
Using basic auth on Kudu like this
service_uri = "https://$kudu_username:kudu_password@myappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/registry/webhook"

works fine however.
Also, once the push event is received by the app service, the pull works fine with the system-managed identity enabled and an 'AcrPull'Azure Role defined on the AppService (linux).

In your case, you can use a system-managed identity to authenticate the container registry to the app service. You can grant the managed identity permission to access the container registry by assigning the "AcrPull" role to the managed identity. You can follow the instructions in the "Use an Azure managed identity to authenticate to an Azure container registry" document to authenticate with Azure Container Registry (ACR) from Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS).

Once the push event is received by the app service, the pull works fine with the system-managed identity enabled and an 'AcrPull' Azure Role defined on the AppService (Linux).

Use an Azure managed identity to authenticate to an ACR
Migrate custom software to App Service using a custom container (container-linux)



I'd like to use a system-managed identity to authenticate the container registry to the app service, or some EntraID application.

To authenticate ACR from the web app with Managed Identity, ensure that you enable the identity on the ACR and select the same identity for the web app. Then, copy the webhook URL.

When I use the below service URL in under webhook creation, I too got the same error(401).
service_uri = "https://${azurerm_linux_web_app.webapp_myapp.name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/registry/webhook"

Webhook Result

Here is the updated Terraform code to create a webhook under ACR for authenticating the web app.

Note: Before creating the webhook, make sure to assign the AcrPull role to the Azure Container Registry System Managed Identity.

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "webapp-rg"
}

data "azurerm_container_registry" "example" {
  name                = "venkatacr"
  resource_group_name = "webapp-rg"
}
resource "azurerm_container_registry_webhook" "cr_webhook_myapp" {
  name                = "enkatwebhooktest"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  registry_name       = data.azurerm_container_registry.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_container_registry.example.location

  service_uri = "https://$demowebapptest:jSDKWgjjhkhkhkhhhQEnvpBPisfya1lD5HN3CaPdJkJx6jQ7dpBK1WCn9mgSdwRvn6Pw@demowebapptest-fhavdphmh5hrbdby.scm.eastus-01.azurewebsites.net/api/registry/webhook"
  status      = "enabled"
  scope       = "venkatimage/nginx"
  actions     = ["push"]
  custom_headers = {
  }
}


Terraform Apply

After executing the Terraform code, the webhook has been successfully created in the ACR and connected to the web app


I used managed identity to connect to Azure Container Registry without the need for a username and password, and I disabled Azure Container Registry Admin access.

As you can read above, it worked that way for me too.
Actual sequence:

docker image push
registry records image
registry sends a push event
appservice pull the image

I could setup the pull using system-managed identity without any problem.
Sending of the push event using kudu basic auth is ok too. In the portal, you have no choice but using the basic auth. This is provided by the webhook url you have to copy paste to the registry serviceuri.
I want some other mechanism than the basic auth for the push event, like system-managed identity and set it up using terraform.
